# Comparator<Object> Parcelable

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, parcelable

After hours of searching, I don't know how to make a Comparator parcelable. 
I found this "Parcelable stuff" a bit "missing content"... (Parcelable don't have even a writeBoolean)

```
public class T implements Parcelable{

   ...

   public static Comparator<T> Compare = new Comparator<T>() {...}

   ...

   public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        //how to write "Compare"
   }

   private T(Parcel in) {
        //how to read "Compare"
   }

}
```

Thank you.

EDIT:

So here is the detail (simplified and adapted) about why the class F must be parcelable. Note that the code comes from a finished iOS project. It will be good for maintenance if the architecture stay the same... :-)

```
public class F implements Parcelable{
    …
    public ArrayList<T> listArray;
    public HashMap<String,Comparator<T>> sortElementMap;
}
```

_

```
public class T implements Parcelable{
    …
    public static Comparator<T> CompareByName = new Comparator<T>() {…}};
    public static Comparator<T> CompareByDate = new Comparator<T>() { … }};
}
```

First, in a configuration class (simplified here) allowing to adapt easily the application (column database matching between variables of T, filter/sort/search definition, ...)

```
F f=new F();
f.sortElementMap.put("name",T.CompareByName)
f.sortElementMap.put("date",T.CompareByDate)
```

In the previous activity

```
Intent intent=new Intent(…);
intent.putExtra("F",F);
startActivity(intent);
```

In the current activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

…
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    f = (F)intent.getParcelableExtra("F");
}


// the list to be sorted
listArray=new ArrayList<String>(f.listArray);

listAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, listArray);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        //@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
        …
        }
    });


// the list with the different type of sorting

sortArray=new ArrayList<String>();
Iterator it = f.sortElementMap.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        sortArray.add((String) pairs.getKey());
    }

sortListAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item_sort, sortArray);
    sortListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.sortListView);
    sortListView.setAdapter(sortListAdapter);
    sortListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        //@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            applyCurrentSelectedSort();

        }
    });


void applyCurrentSelectedSort(){

    Iterator it = f.sortElementMap.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry) it.next();

        for (int i = 0; i < sortListAdapter.getSelectedPosition().length; i++) {
            if (sortListAdapter.getSelectedPosition()[i]) {
                listAdapter.sort((java.util.Comparator<T>) pairs.getValue());
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's static. Why are you even trying to put a static class into a parcelable?

Comment: In an activity, with a `HashMap map <String,Comparator<T>>` passed with an Intent (thus must be Parcelable…): 

`listAdapter.sort((java.util.Comparator<T>) pairs.getValue());
//where pairs is an element of map`

Comment: Can you add your activity code? I agree with @Zhuinden, it doesn't seem like you need to read/write to/from `parcel`

Comment: That's a really **bad** architecture (that's for start). You don't have to parcel your comparators as they are stored not in object of F, but in the class of F. I suggest making a static map OR (and that's better) a enum of sort engines.

Comment: @SemyonDanilov Yes. But the idea is to declare things only in one class. Thus, if you want to add a comparator you don't have to look in all your classes to look where it is used. How can I get the correct comparator with an enum in a far away class without doing: `if("Name") then CompareByName if("Date") then CompareByDate if (...)` Is it possible with Java Reflection? Thank you.

Comment: Reflection is slow, especially on android. You can do this: enum of comparators, and in the object store list of enum names, for example
List<String> comparators = ...;
comparators.put(Comparators.BY_NAME.toString());
String could be easily put to parcel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public enum Comparators {

     BY_NAME(F.CompareByName),
     BY_DATE(F.CompareByDate);

     private Comparator comparator;

     Comparators(final Comparator comparator) {
          this.comparator = comparator;
     }

     public Comparator getComparator() {
          return comparator;
     }

}


...

class F implements Parcelable {

    List<String> comparatorNames = new ArrayList<>();

    ....   ..

    writeToParcel() {

         //write list
    }


    readFromParcel() {

         //read list
    }

}
```

then everywhere you want it:

```
f = (F)intent.getParcelableExtra("F");
Comparator c = Comparators.valueOf(f.getComparatorName(0));
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about this Enum.valueOf(). So finally, the map is <String,String> (key is for txt translation).

Comment: @myz enums in java are very useful :)